# permanently disable trackpoint in Lenovo T440p Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, laptop, lenovo, trackpoint

after looking around a lot I find that by typing `xinput -set-prop 12 135 0` in the terminal I solved the problem of the cursor moving **alone** when nobody is touching it. How can I make to make this change "fixed" so I don't have to type it every time I load or turn it on, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you try placing the command in rc.local:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/rc.local
```

Use nano or kate or leafpad if you don't have the text editor gedit. Right above the final line exit 0, add your command:

```
xinput -set-prop 12 135 0
```

Proofread carefully, save and close the text editor.